# Centering a text within a sliding box?

Tags: html, css

I created a sliding transition to show info about the image when you hover over it (Thanks to [@StepPen-codes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10366783/steppen-codes?tab=profile) for helping me in that). The problem is the text is not centered in the box. Like I have to center each `<div>` with my hand *-there is no way I can do that-*. What I want is the text always centered in the sliding box.

**[Note: I used `margin: 0 auto;`, and `text-align: center;`. I even set `display` statement to `inline-flex` then I used `justify-content: center;`, and `align-items: center;`. But none of them worked to center the text]** 
Here what I was able to create with my code:

```css
body {
  background: rgb(20,20,20);
}

div.img1Cov {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
  background: blue;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

div.img1Cov:hover {
  padding-right: 150px;
}

img.img1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 10;
  filter: grayscale();
}


div.img1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100;
  right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: rgb(45,45,45);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="img1Cov">
      <img class="img1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/34/b5/86/34b58689b0870284621a661a2c538652.png">
      <div class="img1">
        <p>
        Eren Yeager, Age: 20
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="img1Cov">
      <img class="img1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/13/53/db/1353db1b73fc6ac5119fc5140ed64174.jpg">
      <div class="img1">
        <p>
        Kurapika Kurta, Age: 19
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="img1Cov">
      <img class="img1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7c/38/4e/7c384e8c31876584387b859388516770.jpg">
      <div class="img1">
        <p>
        Giorno Giovanna, Age: 15
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You see, only the first one is centered, because I set the statement `right` to `12px`. What I want is all of them centered like the first one.

**[Again, keep in mind: I used `margin: 0 auto;`, and `text-align: center;`. I even set `display` statement to `inline-flex` then I used `justify-content: center;`, and `align-items: center;`. But none of them worked]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: rgb(20,20,20);
}

div.img1Cov {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

div.img1Cov:hover div{
  transform: translateX(150px);
}

.img1Cov img {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 10;
  filter: grayscale();
}


.img1Cov > div {
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  right: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}

p {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: rgb(45,45,45);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="img1Cov">
      <img class="img1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/34/b5/86/34b58689b0870284621a661a2c538652.png">
      <div class="text">
        <p>
        Eren Yeager, Age: 20
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="img1Cov">
      <img class="img1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/13/53/db/1353db1b73fc6ac5119fc5140ed64174.jpg">
      <div class="text">
        <p>
        Kurapika Kurta, Age: 19
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the best solution i can think of. I made the blue box a own object so it doesnt extends the parent. On hover it just moves 150px to the right. I hope this helps, tiimo

Edit: Forgot to say one thing, in theorey u can remove the classes on the objects in img1Cov. They are not needed anymore in this code

Answer (score 1):

Replace the existing css cause we need to modify the structure

```
div.img1Cov {
position: relative;
display: inline-flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin: 5px 0;
transition: 0.5s;
height: 150px;
flex-direction: row;
```

}

```
div.img1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
    transform: translateX(-150px);
    height: inherit;
    background: blue;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 0.4s all;
}
```

remove the hover padding-left and replace with

```
  div.img1Cov:hover div.img1 {
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Prinju. It worked for me, but you were able to just say I have to move the box instead of extending it. Thanks again.

Comment: its not extending,its actually moving the box